# Is there any workaround for the absence of UsersPermissionToUserConsentToAppEnabled in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to check that users consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf is not allowed using Powershell. Originally, this is done using MSOL-CompanyInformation with  UsersPermissionToUserConsentToAppEnabled. However, as deprecation gets closer for MSOL, I can not find any comparable (MgOrganization does not have the same functionality) or work around for the situation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User consent settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-powershell) are now more fine-grained than just on/off. Instead, a customer can choose whether user have the permission to consent for themselves, and if so, which [permission grant policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-app-consent-policies?source=recommendations) (aka "app consent policy") describes when the user will be allowed to consent (e.g. for which apps, for which permissions, etc.)

Using Microsoft Graph v1.0, this setting is stored in the **permissionGrantPoliciesAssigned** collection under the [**defaultUserRolePermissions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/defaultuserrolepermissions?view=graph-rest-1.0) property of the [**authorizationPolicy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authorizationpolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0) singleton.

Using Microsoft Graph PowerShell, you can retrieve the authorization policy with [`Get-MgPolicyAuthorizationPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/get-mgpolicyauthorizationpolicy?view=graph-powershell-1.0), and update it with [`Update-MgPolicyAuthorizationPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/update-mgpolicyauthorizationpolicy?view=graph-powershell-1.0). Both cmdlets are included in the [Microsoft.Graph.Identity.SignIns](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Identity.SignIns) module.

If the collection includes at least one value that begins with "managePermissionGrantsForSelf.", then user consent for self is enabled, subject to the [permission grant policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permissiongrantpolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0) identified by whatever follows the ".".

### Examples

In this first example, **permissionGrantPoliciesAssigned* is empty, indicating user consent is disabled entirely:

```http
GET https://graph.micrsooft.com/v1.0/policies/authorizationPolicy
```

```
{
    /* ... */
    "defaultUserRolePermissions": {
        "allowedToCreateApps": true,
        "allowedToCreateSecurityGroups": true,
        "allowedToReadOtherUsers": true,
        "permissionGrantPoliciesAssigned": [] // <- User consent disabled entirely
    }
}
```

In this second example, user consent is enabled, subject to the permission grant policy with ID "microsoft-user-default-low" (also note that here we're querying **defaultUserRolePermissions** directly):

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/authorizationPolicy/defaultUserRolePermissions
```

```
{
    /* ... */
    "allowedToCreateApps": true,
    "allowedToCreateSecurityGroups": true,
    "allowedToReadOtherUsers": true,
    "permissionGrantPoliciesAssigned": [
        "ManagePermissionGrantsForSelf.microsoft-user-default-low" // <- User consent enabled
    ]
}
```

We can get more details about that built-in policy (we know it's built-in because it starts with "microsoft-") by retrieving it:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/permissionGrantPolicies/microsoft-user-default-low
```

```
{
    "id": "microsoft-user-default-low",
    /* ... */
    "includes": [
        {
            "id": "9c72ced4-50c7-4486-933e-6756d554b199",
            "permissionClassification": "low",
            "permissionType": "delegated",
            "resourceApplication": "any",
            "permissions": [ "all" ],
            "clientApplicationIds": [ "all" ],
            "clientApplicationTenantIds": [ "b6e5dea0-ef49-4100-9191-1bb9c16c40b0" ],
            "clientApplicationPublisherIds": [ "all" ],
            "clientApplicationsFromVerifiedPublisherOnly": false
        },
        {
            "id": "8ce99f96-730c-4ebd-8397-07ee65942b97",
            "permissionClassification": "low",
            "permissionType": "delegated",
            "resourceApplication": "any",
            "permissions": [ "all" ],
            "clientApplicationIds": [ "all" ],
            "clientApplicationTenantIds": [ "all" ],
            "clientApplicationPublisherIds": [ "all" ],
            "clientApplicationsFromVerifiedPublisherOnly": true
        }
    ],
    "excludes": []
}
```

We can see this policy includes two [condition sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permissiongrantconditionset?view=graph-rest-1.0):

- All delegated permissions classified "low", for apps registered in the same tenant*
- All delegated permissions classified "low", for apps with a verified publisher

*In this special built-in permission grant policy, **clientApplicationTenantIds** will always be the tenant ID of the tenant where the policy is being read from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use permissionGrantPolicyIdsAssignedToDefaultUserRole property to update authorizationPolicy,

PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/authorizationPolicy/authorizationPolicy

for more please check doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authorizationpolicy-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

[image]
[image]

**Note**: Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Note that this _is_ available in Microsoft Graph v1.0, under `.../policies/authorizationPolicy/defaultUserRolePermissions/permissionGrantPoliciesAssigned`.